# Tone marks placement problem using python PIL vs GD php

Tags: python

I try to create images from text using Python and PHP.
At first, I'm using Python `PIL` everything seemed to work except the tone mark position
overlapped. So I change to PHP which the tone mark position is quite correct compared to Python.
So I would like to ask if is there anywhere to correct the position of the tone mark in Python.
Searching everywhere but there is no clue on how to correct this.

[image]